# How can I set the maximum length of an xmltype?

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I've created a table with the following:

```
create table mytable
(
primary_key varchar(30),
Myxml xmltype,
mydate    DATE   
);
```

When run `describe mytable` I get:

```
Name               Null Type         
------------------ ---- ------------ 
PRIMARY_KEY             VARCHAR2(30) 
MYXML                   XMLTYPE()    
MYDATE                  DATE
```

The problem is, I'm using a propertery software that wants to convert a dataset and upload it to this table, when it run it it gives me a proprietary error:

`Value too large for column myxml. Max length = 0, actual length = 1721`

Is there a way that I can manually set the max length of `MYXML` to avoid this?

Comment: There is no maximum size on an `XMLType`.  Or, rather, the limit is depends on the underlying implementation which would depend on the size of the underlying `LOB`.  That will depend on the specific version of Oracle and the database block size but that's probably in the range of a few TB.  Without being able to see what the actual Oracle error is, it's hard to guess where this message is really coming from.

Comment: @JustinCave - Yes it's a proprietary/compiled software, so it's a bit hard to tell what's going on with it. I do have an idea though - the problem is more that the data I'm uploading is as a string, so I need to convert that into XMLtype. Was thinking of doing that with a trigger or a view.

Comment: A string *literal*  can not be longer than 4000 **bytes** in Oracle (pre 12c). This includes literal values for XMLType columns. 1721 characters could very well be the length of a XML literal that contains many multi-byte characters. This can only be fixed in the application using prepared statements. I don't believe it's fixable from the outside